# WFI instruction slowing down SYStick interrupt

Tags: arm, embedded, assembly, cortex-m4

I've configured my Infineon relax kit for max frequency(120 MHz). I've set my SYSTick for a periodic interrupt of 10 ms. For power saving, I use a WFI assembler instruction whenever my processor is idle. WFI (wait for interrupt) should put the processor in low power mode until an interrupt occurs. So my processor should wake up after every 10 ms. But somehow, this WFI instruction slowed down my interrupt frequency to almost 3 times and it wakes up on every third interrupt. 
What can be possible reason for WFI not waking up on every interrupt?

Comment: Does the datasheet say anything about how long it takes to wake up from low power mode? Does it also mention the interrupt latency and any delay in getting to max frequency? Can you provide a link to the datasheet? Which clock runs during low power mode?

Comment: How do you know that it only wakes up every third interrupt?  Is it possible that your MCU goes into some deeper sleep mode, which reduces the core frequency?

Comment: Link to the datasheet:
http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/infineon/xmc4500/xmc4500_um.pdf

Datasheet does not say anything about interrupt latency. I've enabled system clock(CCU) in SleepCR register to counter any effects of clock gating but to no avail. @Roger Rowland

Comment: @corecode 
I have a variable that increments on every systick interrupt. Without WFI, it increments to a 1000 in 10 seconds, but with WFI, it increments to only 330. So this means that my interrupt's been handled on every third call. Or alternatively, my effective frequency has reduced to 3 times.
My MCU goes in sleep mode(not deep sleep) by default.

Comment: Cortex M4F need 6 cycles to get back up from normal WFI, shouldn't be a problem if the clocks stay the same (which I try to find out but the user manual is horrible). Can you output the clock used for systick and probe what happens if you go to WFI?

Comment: @Arsenal Actually I cannot output the clock. There are obviously more than 6 cycles in 10 ms when you're running on 120MHz. Can WFI possibly gate the system clock too which is producing interrupts on SYSTick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with these devices, but in the [user manual it is mentioned](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/infineon/xmc4500/xmc4500_um.pdf#page=484) that:

> The Sleep state of the system corresponds to the Sleep state of the
>   CPU. The state is entered via WFI or WFE instruction of the CPU. In
>   this state the clock to the CPU is stopped. **The source of the system
>   clock may be altered.** Peripherals clocks are gated according to the 
>   SLEEPCR register.

Taking a look at the [SLEEPCR register](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/infineon/xmc4500/xmc4500_um.pdf#page=607) description shows:

```
Field  Bits Type Description 
SYSSEL 0    rwh  System Clock Selection Value
                 0 -> f OFI clock, 1 -> f PLL clock
```

as the reset value of said register is 0, it defaults to the \$f_{OFI}\$ clock. Which runs at 36.5 MHz uncalibrated or 24 MHz calibrated. It has a rather huge accuracy range if uncalibrated (see the [datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-XMC4500-DS-v01_03-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624933b875014960b0bd234392&sd=t)) of at least +-15%, together with the fact that you will get some systicks with 120 MHz in again during your execution it might well turn out to be roughly 40MHz in average.

Solution (hopefully): Set the SYSSEL bit to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It didn't occur to me. I was setting CCU bit in SLEEPCR register.